# Adding forwardIcon into a programmatically created UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift4, uibezierpath

I have a UIButton created programmatically and I need to add a forward icon which has to be created using UIBezierPath as shown in the figure below. How do I do that . I am a beginner in iOS and I need help. 
[The end result  I want is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5hNW.png)

The code I have is this:

```
let forwardButton : UIButton = {
    let fb = UIButton()
    fb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    fb.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.56, green:0.07, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
    return fb
}()

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    forwardButton.bounds.size.width
    forwardButton.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

I have code for circular button but I don't know how to draw forward icon using bezierpath inside the circular button. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code :

```
fb.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourImageName.png"), for: .normal)
```

If you are using xcasset you can use (no need .png):

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "Done") {
   fb.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```